# PHP - Soapclient - Basic Auth -> SERVER->REMOTE_USER

Tags: php, apache-2.4, soap

We use a PHP Soap-Webservice on a 1und1-Server.
If i call the Service like

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://server.com/test.wsdl',
array('login'    => "tuser",
    'password' => "tpass",
    'trace' => 1)
);
```

all works fine and in my Server the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'`] is set.

Now our company wants to transfer the service to a server on Microsoft Azure.
On this Server the code doesn't work the same way. The Basic auth works but there is no `$_SERVER['REMOTE-USER']` variable set in my service.
If i check the `$_SERVER` at all, there are nor vars with my login-user.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is "a server on Microsoft Azure"?